# RobotFramework: Getting string value back from sql query

Tags: robotframework

Doing a database query that returns multiple rows...

```
${visits_for_this_patient}=  Select from Database
...  Select to_char(visit_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from patient_visits where patient_id=${patient_id} order by visit_date
${list_of_visits_for_this_patient}=  create list  ${visits_for_this_patient}
Row Count Should Be Equal To X
...  Select * from patient_visits where patient_id=${patient_id}
...  ${expected_number_of_patients_for_this_visit}
...  ${SPONSOR_NAME}
```

How can i take a specific row's string value back without the padding? Im getting like

(b'2017-03-03',)

when i try ${visits_for_this_patient[0]}

Answer (score 2):

You have to go one level deeper - the return value of а db query is a list of tuples (that's how the underlying python modules return the data).

E.g. it looks like this:

```
[(b'2017-03-03',)]
```

When you call `${visits_for_this_patient[0]}`, you get the 1st member of the list - a tuple (what you saw yourself). To get the actual value, just get that value's first member (the 1st member of the tuple); so simply:

```
${visits_for_this_patient[0][0]}
```

The end value of that should be `2017-03-03` (as a string).